# How can I keep the width-height ratio of the background image and respectively choose which side to set to standard between width and height?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do on the background image is to expand width or height depending on the ratio of the browser size compared to that of the background image.

In this one the image is (almost) not streched; and I want the image to keep its original ratio. Basically, The width and height of background image would follow those of the browser screen.

[image]

In this screenshot, the image must be expanded to up and down because its width/height ratio is larger than the original. And the exceeded parts should be out of the browser pane.

[image]

In this one, the width/height ratio is smaller; as long as keeping its ratio and fitting the image height to the browser's height, the image should be stretched to left and right.

[image]

Hope you to understand what I want to do.. I think I might have to use something like `if-then` statement to detect the browser ratio and respectively change which side to fit to the image. Or are some other techs required to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the help of Javascript, I would suggest to use:

```
body {
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The `background-position: 50% 50%` will center the image horizontally and vertically. The `background-size: cover` will make the image cover the whole body.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u4bqu63q/)